# Custom field into Aggregation with MONGO

Tags: java, mongodb

Is it possible to add 2 custom fields (that are not exist at my collections), into aggregate group query, using java with mongoDB? My approach is below but it doesn't work

```
    Double custom_calculated_field1 = 0d;
    Double custom_calculated_field2 = 0d;
    Document customGroup_fields = new Document();
    customGroup_fields.append("customer_id", "$customer_id");
    //custom_calculated fields
    customGroup_fields.append("custom_calculated_field1", custom_calculated_field1);
    customGroup_fields.append("custom_calculated_field2", custom_calculated_field2);
         AggregateIterable<Document> customers_results = customerID.aggregate(
            Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(values),
                    Aggregates.group(customGroup_fields)
            ));
```

Comment: What is your document before and what would you like it to look like after? Also, the aggregation won't really "add" anything since it is only aggregating it. If you want to add fields you require a projection. Your code seems to be defining groupings?

Comment: Why do you have to add the custom fields to the group ? Can't you just add it to returned results ? Just trying to understand the use case. Btw what is not working when you try the way you have ?

Comment: At the final, i want to return a json object, which contains user id and the two other custom fields grouped by user.

Comment: I believe you are missing the keywords. An aggregation pipeline is undefined in terms of what has to happen first. So your match isn't really a match and your grouping is not a group. You need to tell the pipeline what it is meant to do. I have an example using DBObjects, not one with Documents. If you want i can post that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the way you structure your aggregation. You can read more about it on the Mongo aggregation docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Effectively you assume that your pipeline knows what operations you are trying to execute. A pipeline however works very similar to what a unix pipe `|` does. It executes any command and passes the output to the next. So you need to tell it that your match is a match and the group is a group. I have an example for both `Document` and `DBObject`, where `DBObject` is the more up to date approach I believe. Consider this example:

```
  @Test
    public void testAggProjection() { 
        DBCollection collection = template.getCollection("test-collection");

        DBObject ob = new BasicDBObject(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value1", "something", "here"));
        DBObject ob2 = new BasicDBObject(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value1", "hello", "world"));
        DBObject ob3 = new BasicDBObject(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value2", "other", "fields"));
        WriteResult insert = collection.insert(ob, ob2, ob3);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, insert.getN());

        DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("test", "value1")); // match the test value 
        Map<String, Object> grouping = new HashMap<>();
        grouping.put("_id", "$test");
        grouping.put("my_count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", grouping); // group by 

        AggregationOutput aggregate = collection.aggregate(match, group);
        System.out.println(aggregate.results());
        DBObject next = aggregate.results().iterator().next();
        Assert.assertTrue(next.containsField("_id"));
        Assert.assertTrue(next.containsField("my_count"));


        // with documents raw 
        MongoClient mc = (MongoClient) client;
        MongoCollection<Document> collection2 = mc.getDatabase(template.getDb().getName()).getCollection("test-collection");

        Document dob = new Document(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value1", "something", "here"));
        Document dob2 = new Document(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value1", "hello", "world"));
        Document dob3 = new Document(ImmutableMap.of("test", "value2", "other", "fields"));

        collection2.insertMany(Arrays.asList(dob, dob2, dob3));

        long count = collection2.count();
        Assert.assertEquals(3, count);

        Document match2 = new Document("$match", new Document("test", "value1"));
        Document group2 = new Document("$group", ImmutableMap.of("_id", "$test", "my_count", new Document("$sum", 1)));

        AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate2 = collection2.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match2, group2));
        Document next2 = aggregate2.iterator().next();
        Assert.assertTrue(next2.get("_id") != null);
        Assert.assertTrue(next2.get("my_count") != null);
    }
```

This is a working unit test. What this does is (in both cases):

- Create a new collection and insert 3 documents.
- Aggregate them with a match, matching 2 documents, and a group where we count the objects we found.

The important bits for you are here:

```
Document match2 = new Document("$match", new Document("test", "value1"));
        Document group2 = new Document("$group", ImmutableMap.of("_id", "$test", "my_count", new Document("$sum", 1)));

        AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate2 = collection2.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match2, group2));
```

In my `match2` and `group2` documents, I define what stage the aggregation is executing as `$match` and `$group`.

The resulting Json is then:

```
Document{{_id=value1, my_count=2}}
```

I hope that helps!

Please note that the `_id` field inside the group is mandatory.

Artur